# integrar font awebsome en pagina HTML

Tags: javascript, html, font-awesome

Como puedo integrar el catalogo de iconos de font awebsome en mi pagina y cuando el usuario seleccione uno pueda saber el tag del icono que selecciono el usuario

Comment: pues lo de incluirlo es como cualquier hoja de estilos. Aquí se explica en la [documentacíon](http://fontawesome.io/get-started/) y lo de obtener el tag pues extrayendo la clase dependiendo si la haces con js puro o algún framework

Comment: @ReneLimon lo quiero hacer con JS

Answer (score 1):

lo unico que debes ha`<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">` en el `<head></head>`  y posteriormente ver el catalogo de iconos y copiar y pegar desde aqui [Aqui](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)

por ejmplo

```
<i class="fa fa-address-book-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

si lo quieres hacer con javascript solo usa `innerHtml("<i class='fa fa-address-book-o' aria-hidden='true'></i>");`